# unwanted gap between paper border and hbox

Tags: titles, boxes, geometry

I am creating the title page for my thesis, and I need this red rectangle right next to the top margin, but the following code generates a (very) small gap between the top of the box and the paper border:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,
%           showframe,
%           showcrop,
            top=0mm,
            left=15mm,
            right=0mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}  
\begin{titlepage}

\mbox{}\hfill\hbox{\pdfliteral{0.64 0 0 rg}\vrule height4mm width128mm depth0cm\pdfliteral{0 g}}

\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

If I set the top margin as 0mm, why this gap exists?

Comment: As for the "why": TeX is still leaving space for a line of text (so I guess sa much as `\baselineskip` but I'm not quite sure).